# What is the policy on carrying liquor in transit through Germany?

Tags: transit, airport-security, lufthansa, fra

I will be travelling from India to US on Lufthansa and have a stopover in Frankfurt. I'd like to know if I can purchase liquor in India from a duty free shop and if it would be allowed by airport security while in transit through Frankfurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what is written on their [website](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/travel/transfer.detail.suffix.html/article/travel/services-a-z/easy-travel/transfer-at-fra.html), the correct answer to this question is **Yes, you can**. I was able to carry liquor purchased at delhi airport through FRA airport (on 2/18/19). It has to be in a tamper proof sealed bag.

Answer (score 8):

[You can't](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/travel/transfer.detail.suffix.html/article/travel/services-a-z/easy-travel/transfer-at-fra.html).

> Please note that you may not carry liquids bought in duty free shops at airports outside the EU when flying from Frankfurt Airport. This also applies to any duty-free items that you have bought on board a non-EU airline.